# Binary compatibility in 2015 visual studio

Tags: c++

One of the legacy application which build in 2010 visual studio(native application) need to be upgraded its one of the DLL which build in visual studio 15, is this possible?

Comment: It depends. Will you change the order of the functions in the DLL? Or remove any functions from the DLL? Or change the interface (e.g. function signatures)? If the order of everything is the same, and there is nothing removed, and no existing function signature changes, then it should work fine.

Comment: @some: order is irrelevant. Linking is by name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the *interface* uses types from the C++ Standard Library, such as `std::string`, it's unlikely to work. These types generally come from the C++ runtime, and the two versions have different runtime libraries.

If the interface uses `LPCSTR`, the implementation can use any string library internally (standard, Qt, etc)

Comment: Yeah, even I have same doubt, fortunately this particular DLL is working fine without any issue.